# Ocr.read() function exit the application unexpectedly c#

Tags: c#, pdf, ocr

the code is supposed to recognize the english text in the pdf ,
when run the code in my machine the code run well, but when run it in
any other machine the app exit unexpectedly without raise any exception ,
when debug the code it arrives to this line and exit
var Result = Ocr.Read(Input);
belw is my function :

```cs
    private void SearchPDF(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
            if (new FileInfo(fileName).Length == 0)
            {
                return;
            }
    
            var Ocr = new IronTesseract();
    
            Ocr.Language = OcrLanguage.English;
            using (var Input = new OcrInput(fileName))
            {
                var Result = Ocr.Read(Input);
                string currentSubText = Result.Text;
                text.Append(currentSubText);
    
            }
            string searchWord = "";
            txtSearch.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { searchWord = txtSearch.Text.ToLower(); });
            string fileData = text.ToString();
            string fileNameWithExt = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName);
            if (isIN(fileNameWithExt, fileData, searchWord))
            {
                matchingPdfFiles.Add(fileNameWithExt, fileName);
                fillInTable(fileName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe try checking Windows Event Viewer to see if there is any errors caught in the applications log.  But you may be able to improve your `catch`.  You aren't catching any exception, just throwing.

Comment: That try/catch is worse than useless, as it not only fails to do anything useful with the error information but also throws a new exception with a new stack trace and no useful message, so any information about what went wrong that might have helped you is lost. Fix this, and then edit the question to post the exception message. Then we will be able to help you more.

Comment: thanks for your comments, but the when i debug the code ,the app exit and not arrives to catch block

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn look to the code after edit

Comment: @TimothyG. look to the code after edit

Comment: Okay, this is better. Now let's add a few more calls to MessageBox.Show() to the method. You can use them to narrow down which section and then line of code creates the crash.

Comment: i did this ,the line that creates the crash :
 var Result = Ocr.Read(Input);